# What schemas are needed for the website?

Tags: google

I am creating a schema for a website and I don't know what kind of schema is required.

At the moment, I only have schema for business information on homepage.

What other types of schema do I need to set. And does placing multiple schemas count as spam?

Thanks for any ideas

Comment: More here https://twitter.com/Jammer_Volts/status/1249877092990210049?s=20

Comment: Which schemas to bother with depend on what search features you're going for. Which types of rich snippets are you trying to achieve? Here's a list: https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/search-gallery

Comment: "Need" is a strong word.  Schemas don't help with search engine rankings.   Some schemas enable rich snippets in the search results, but none of them may be applicable to your site.  Most sites are fine without implementing any schemas at all.

Answer (score 0):

Multiple schemas is fine.

Best place to start is Google Webmasters, head over to Structured Data Markup Helper, this will provide you with a list of schemas you can create.